# Is there a way to test if a gem is working? Or a way to see what functions it has

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

What is the best way to see if a ruby gem is working properly?

I have just installed https://github.com/watu/table_builder

When I try to use basic example my application returns "undefined method `table_for' for #<#< Class:0x12a69e738>:0x12a699580>"

I originaly found this through the rails cast http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars

Does anyony know what I've done wrong in this case? or even better how do I debug in a situation like this.

Is there a way to print all available helper methods or anything like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use bundler to install the gems you can do:

```
bundle show table_builder #show gem path
bundle open table_builder #open gem in default editor
```

Without bundler:

```
gem which table_builder #show gem path
#then open it...
```

In general you can see the code of all installed gems when you know their location. Then just debug the code ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just import the code in your own project (put it in lib or vendor/plugins folder) and see where is that exception raised. That will give you a clear view what the problem is.